# AutoComplete with multiple suggestions

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am new to Jquery and Ajax. I want autocomplete in  such a manner that,
for example user enters NEW(consider city names here) in search box then suggestions should be starting with NEW like

```
 ---cities
```

NEWYork

NEW DELHI

```
 ----newyork airports
```

xyz

abc

pqr

```
 ----new dehli airports
```

some airport name

some airport name

some airport name

how can i implement the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the typeahead library ?

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/